# VBA Code Finds Less Values Than Excel's Default Find Function

Tags: excel, vba, count

I have the following code which I use to count how many occurrences there are from a specific value:

```
LastRow = Sheet10.Cells(Sheet10.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

counter = 0
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Sheet10.Range("G" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Now the result of "counter" remains always lower than the actual number of matches. For example, when I use Excel's default Find function "Ctrl+F", the result is higher than the VBA code counts. (The variable "LastRow" returns the actual number of rows.)

How can I count all the occurrences in VBA?

Comment: Are they the same case? any trailing spaces?  Have you tried forcing the range of i to a suspect row and debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out with the following code:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Set findRange = Sheet10.Range("G" & i).Find(Sheet1.Range("C4"))
    If findRange Is Nothing Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i
```

I needed to use the `.Find` function. Now it finally counts all occurrences. It may not be the best solution, but it works for me.